# ADO.NET SQLite pcl library for Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, windows-runtime, ado.net

Is there available ADO.NET pcl library for sqlite? It can be also simple (not pcl) library. I am looking especially support for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1 metro app). As I know there is mono implementation of ado.net for Android and IOS. But I cannot find any implementation for Windows Runtime.

The libraries like sqlite-net-pcl are not applicable, because I need to create dynamic set of data.

Comment: WinRT version of Microsoft.Data.SQLite : https://github.com/TheBlueSky/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.WinRT

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a solution. I am wondering if I should use it because this library is very immature.

Comment: Its based on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite that is actively maintained by Microsoft and both are OSS...

Answer (score 0):

Since `ADO.NET` is fairly old, it's more of a platform implementation rather than a PCL-available class. However you could write your own wrapper in which `Windows` platforms would call into `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` or `System.Data` and `Mono/Xamarin` platforms would call into `Mono.Data.Sqlite`.

Seeing that `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` is now more portable(available in `netstandard1.3`), you should be able to just use `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` in your projects as long as you target `netstandard1.3+` as a means to get a `DbConnection` in true `ADO.NET` fashion.

Comment: I can't write wrapper for Microsoft.Data.Sqlite or System.Data since this libraries are not available for Windows Runtime platform. I can't call full framework libraries from Windows Runtime (can I?). Also I cannot use netstandard 1.3 library since Windows Runtime targets netstandard 1.2.